# Read only nth first lines [sublime text]

Tags: sublimetext3

I've got some files so big to directly open them in Sublime Text. Is there any way to open only the nth first lines? Something like `head` in *bash*? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux or Mac, or have Cygwin, Git Bash, or similar installed on a Windows machine, check out the [`split`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)) utility, which is part of the [`coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package. It does exactly what it says: it splits input into separate files. It is configurable via command-line options, like every Unix utility. For example, if you wanted to split your input file into separate 10,000-line files starting with `notsobigfile` and using numeric suffixes ending with `.txt`, you would run

```bash
split -d -l 10000 --additional-suffix=".txt" reallybigfile.txt notsobigfile
```

and it would output files named `notsobigfile01.txt`, `notsobigfile02.txt`, etc. If this would generate more than 100 files (`00` through `99`), just add `-a x` where `x` is the number of digits (the default is 2).

For all the possible options, just read the `man` page:

```bash
man split
```

If you only want to output the first part of the file, check out the options for the `-n`/`--number` flag.

To figure out how many lines your input file has, run the word counting utility using the lines option:

```bash
wc -l reallybigfile.txt
```

Comment: It's a nice alternative bu, then,  I guess there's no other option inside Sublime, right?

Comment: @jgarces correct, Sublime only reads whole files AFAIK.

Comment: @jgarces there's actually one more way you can go about it that doesn't involve making temp files - piping the output from `head` to Sublime's stdin. You'll need `bash`, `zsh`, or similar, and you'll need to be running Sublime Text 4 (check **`Help → About`** and make sure the build number is above 4000) with `subl` on your `PATH`. Just run `head -50 reallybigfile.txt | subl -` and you'll get the first 50 lines in Sublime.